# Get data from same table

Tags: mysql

I have one query about fetch the data.

## table name:sub_element

### se_id | se_name

1 | GHSB 
2 | ENGLISH
3 | GUJ
4 | RUSSIAN
5 | FRENCH
6 | S1 
7 | S2 
8 | S3

## table name = class_standard

### cs_id | board_se_id | medium_se_id | s_se_id

1 | 1 | 2 | 6,7
2 | 3 | 4 | 6,8

## table name:class_standard_subject

### css_id | cs_id | se_id

1 | 1 | 6 
2 | 1 | 7 
3 | 2 | 6 
4 | 2 | 8

expected output is: 
GHSB | ENGLISH | S1,S2
GUJ | RUSSIAN | S1,S3

Both data are from same table.
How to achieve this type of output.
Please help.

I tried this query but not getting expected output:

```
select t1.*,a1.* FROM ((
SELECT cs.cs_id, se.se_name as bname FROM sub_element se, class_standard cs WHERE cs.board = se.se_id GROUP BY cs.cs_id) as a1,
(SELECT se.se_name as mname FROM sub_element se, class_standard cs WHERE cs.medium = se.se_id GROUP BY cs.cs_id ) as t1)
```

Comment: What output **are** you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `sub_element` 2 times as

```
select
se1.se_name as se_name1,
se2.se_name as se_name2
from class_standard cs
join sub_element se1 on se1.id = cs.board_se_id
join sub_element se2 on se2.id = cs.medium_se_id
```

UPDATE : With the updated question you have comma separated values and you should avoid these since its not properly normalized and lead into many issues in future.
However you can achieve the result as

```
select  
cs.cs_id,se1.se_name as se_name1,  
se2.se_name as se_name2, 
group_concat(se3.se_name) as se_name3  
from class_standard cs  
join sub_element se1 on se1.se_id = cs.board_se_id  
join sub_element se2 on se2.se_id = cs.medium_se_id  
left join sub_element se3 on find_in_set(se3.se_id,cs.s_se_id) 
group by cs.cs_id ;
```

Comment: i made 3rd table for that. but from there how can i get data?

Comment: Please post a new question if you have something new.

Comment: it isn't new. you told that normalize the structure.. so i made 3rd table

Comment: Ok then do a left join to that table and you can still show them as comma-separated using `group_concat`, just change the above query and left join to the new table without find_in_set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74491/discussion-between-rick-and-abhik-chakraborty).

Comment: i m not getting expected o/p. i made changes as u said

Comment: Sorry but really hard to understand what you are trying. Thats why I said add a new question with the proper table data and what you tried.

Comment: i added it in this question

Comment: This should be the query `select 
se1.se_name as se_name1, 
se2.se_name as se_name2,
group_concat(se3.se_name) as se_name3  
from class_standard cs 
join sub_element se1 on se1.se_id = cs.board_se_id 
join sub_element se2 on se2.se_id = cs.medium_se_id 
left join class_standard_subject css on css.cs_id = cs.cs_id
left join sub_element se3 on se3.se_id = css.se_id
group by cs.cs_id;
`